# Inheritance from generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I don't know how to solve a problem with generic interfaces.

Generic interface represents factory for objects:

```
interface IFactory<T>
{
    // get created object
    T Get();    
}
```

Interface represents factory for computers (Computer class) specyfing general factory:

```
interface IComputerFactory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : Computer
{
    // get created computer
    new Computer Get();
}
```

Generic interface represents special factory for objects, which are cloneable (implements interface System.ICloneable):

```
interface ISpecialFactory<T> where T : ICloneable, IFactory<T>
{
    // get created object
    T Get();
}
```

Class represents factory for computers (Computer class) and cloneable objects:

```
class MyFactory<T> : IComputerFactory<Computer>, ISpecialFactory<T>
{

}
```

I get compiler error messages In MyFactory class:

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'exer.ISpecialFactory<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'exer.IFactory<T>'.   

The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'exer.ISpecialFactory<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.ICloneable'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if this is a typo, but should this:

```
interface ISpecialFactory<T>
        where T : ICloneable, IFactory<T>
```

have really been

```
interface ISpecialFactory<T> : IFactory<T>
        where T : ICloneable
```

Really, I think this is probably what you're trying to do:

```
public class Computer : ICloneable
{ 
    public object Clone(){ return new Computer(); }
}

public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Get();    
}

public interface IComputerFactory : IFactory<Computer>
{
    Computer Get();
}

public interface ISpecialFactory<T>: IFactory<T>
    where T : ICloneable
{
    T Get();
}

public class MyFactory : IComputerFactory, ISpecialFactory<Computer>
{
    public Computer Get()
    {
        return new Computer();
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ENLPO67010

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not exactly what i want to achieve. Could you changed it in such a way that MyFactory produce all cloneable objects, not only "Computer" objects?

Comment: @Matt - Sorry that doesn't make much sense. If the factory doesn't get concreted, how does it know *how* to construct something? Even in your original post `MyFactory` implemented `IComputerFactory`. You should update your question with a bit more context on *what you are trying to achieve*

Comment: If the factory doesn't get concreted, how does it know how to construct something? I thought using generics. Im my original posts MyFactory implements IComputerFactory interface and ISpecialFactory interface. It means MyFactory is able to produce not only instances of Computer class, but also instances of all classes that are cloneable. I thought it's possible with new method in myFactory class, something like public T Get {return new T()}. I don't know if it's possible...

Comment: So you want `MyFactory` to both Construct `Computer` as well as construct *any* `ICloneable`? Seems a bit weird, but ok let me revisit my answer

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know, it's weired. I would like to know if it's possible.

Comment: @Matt - I dont think it is. How do you choose between `IComputerFactory.Get` and `ISpecialFactory.Get` when you've only got 1 type argument. I think you need to describe what you're trying to achieve there is almost certainly a more sane way to do it.

Comment: I want to achieve only what I said. How do you choose between IComputerFactory.Get and ISpecialFactory.Get? I thought using explicit interface implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I guess your definition of `ISpecialFactory<T>` is incorrect. Change it to:

```
interface ISpecialFactory<T> : IFactory<T>
    where T : ICloneable
{
    // get created object
    T Get();
}
```

You possibly don't want the `T` type to implement `IFactory<T>`!

Answer (score 2):

Try this this code block:

```
class MyFactory<T> : IComputerFactory<Computer>, ISpecialFactory<T>
    where T: ICloneable, IFactory<T>
    {

    }
```

Comment: This would require `T` to implement `IFactory<T>`.